# Show graphical element/view when tapping on android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Like the image. I am trying to make something like this. When i click my sidemenu that consists of textviews that represents numbers. I want to be able to show what number the user are holding his finger on. So in this case. I was holding my finger over the number 14 and 14:00 is showing on the left side of it.

So does anyone have a good approach for me to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use a fastscroll like feature. Try to take a look at the example code [here](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/). Then you have to customize it to your needs.

Or you can also try a different approach using a PopupMenu on the list element click.

A third approach could be using a PopupWindow, and showing it using showAsDropDown() method, passing the anchor view (in your case the list element clicked)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am going to try the third approach. Sounds very interesting. I wil come back to accept the answer if any of your advice works. Thanks a lot